# Unexpacted value inside Vector when using filestream to insert data

Tags: c++, templates, stream, stringstream

I got a template class in which I got a function which should read the content of a textfile and create a object which is being pushed into an own implemented vector class. I can compile the code but I get an error regarding the a very large number on the 0th element in the vector. (This is an error generated by a script which is provided for error handling and is not any c++ compiler error.)

The code looks like this:

```
bool FileReading(const std::string &nameOfFile)
{
    std::ifstream readFileObj(nameOfFile);
    if (readFileObj.is_open())
    {
        T input;
        readFileObj >> input;
        PushBack(input);

        readFileObj.close();
        return true;
    }
    return false;
}
```

The variable *T input* is a template variable and the function *PushBack* is a function that is pushing the object into the vector. (Not the std push_back function)

Am I missing something obvious? Something elementary regarding how streams work?

Here is my PushBack function:

```
void PushBack(const T &element)
{
    if (currentElementCount == maximumCapacity)
    {
        T *tempArray = new T[maximumCapacity * 2];
        for (unsigned int i = 0; i < maximumCapacity; ++i)
            tempArray[i] = normalArray[i];
        delete[] normalArray;
        maximumCapacity *= 2;
        normalArray = tempArray;
    }
    normalArray[currentElementCount] = element;
    currentElementCount += 1;
}
```

Comment: Sounds like the problem may revolve around the vector, so you should show the implementation of `PushBack` and/or the code that manipulates the vector.

Comment: Updated @TheUndeadFish

Answer (score 0):

I am unsure that I have a proper grasp of the context in which these operations are being performed, but a couple thoughts come to mind that might help out some:

1. Your for-loop in the function `PushBack` begins by initializing the value of `i` to 0, but then your advancement step is `++i`. This pre-increment will bump `i` up to a value of 1, and then only after that will the body of the for-loop be performed. I suspect this might mean that you are skipping putting anything into index 0 altogether and might be running into trouble later when you're trying to access an (invalid) object. Maybe you would have better luck changing this bit to `i++`?
2. Is this templated type T able to be read in from a single item? I see you have `T input; readFileObj >> input;`, but is that all you need for an item T or do you maybe need to read in a few things to create a T that will be pushed into your vector? If this is the case, the problem might be as simple as misaligning your input stream and I could see some error about invalid objects making sense.